# If the product is a monomial, then each function is a monomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-functions, monomial-function

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be analytic functions that passes through origin, i.e., $f(\boldsymbol 0) = g(\boldsymbol 0) = 0$. Is true that if the product $fg$ is a monomial,i.e., has simple normal crossings, then $f$ and $g$ have simple normal crossings? I am asking this because if we have a [desingularization for the zero set](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.09775) for the product, then each function has simple normal crossings, which is already quite good for me.

This result was taken from [Lemma 3.4](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1990-317-02/S0002-9947-1990-0943608-5/). The worst part is that he does not have proven the result, and I am not sure if @lulu counterexemple fits as a counterexemple. Here what is needed is just a  desingularized set of functions $\{f,g\}$ in the author's definition, which is what I have asked.

Comment: What about $f(x)=xe^x$, $g(x)=xe^{-x}$?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the right counterexemple now, but it looks so. I will add some conext. =)

Comment: You would consider those $xe^x$ and $xe^{-x}$ monomial, since $e^{x}$ invertible in the local ring ar $0$. If $fg$ is monomial and $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ a local coordinate system in which it is monomial, then each $x_i$ that appears in the monomial with positive exponent must divide at least one of $f$ or $g$, since $(x_i)$ are prime. Cancelling that factor, you get to cancel the entire monomial. So, you reduce to the case that $fg$ is a unit. But then you got that the original $f$ and $g$ are a product of the products of the $x_1$ that you cancelled times units.

Comment: You can write a answear, @plop. =) I'm new with these concepts. I would the thankful for your explanation and references, if possible.